# Wordpress ajax form nonce fails

Tags: ajax, wordpress, nonce

I have a email form in Wordpress and I'm using ajax to with it.

I'm creating a nonce in the form and checking it before I send the email.

The nonce fails but the output shows it is the same nonce.

Simified code:

The email form

```
    <form class="email-form" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Full Name</label>    
            <input type="text" class="email-name input-lg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>    
            <input type="text" class="email-email input-lg"/>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="ajax-nonce" id="ajax-nonce" value="' <?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'email-nonce' ); ?>'" />

        <div class="form-group email-submit">
            <button class="btn-green email-submit">Send</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

The js

```
    $('.email-submit').on('click', function(e){     

        e.preventDefault();

        var mc_name = $('.email-name').val();
        var mc_email = $('.email-email').val();
        var mc_nonce = $('#ajax-nonce').val();

        alert(mc_nonce);

        classData = {
            'type' : 'post', 
            'action' : 'classajax-submit',
            'dataType' : 'jsonp',
            'crossDomain' : true,
            'nonce' : mc_nonce,

            'the_name' : mc_name, 
            'the_email' : mc_email,

        }

        $.post(TheAjax.ajaxurl, classData).done(function(result){        

            if(result == 'success') {

                //success message

            }
          }, 'jsonp');
    })
```

Functions.php

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

    function add_my_script() {
      wp_enqueue_script('scripts',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/compiled/main.min.js', array('jquery'));
      //
      wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'TheAjax', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
      ));
    }


    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_classajax-submit', 'classajax_submit' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_classajax-submit', 'classajax_submit' );

    function classajax_submit() {

        $nonce = stripslashes($_POST['nonce']);

        echo 'nonce in php ' . $nonce; 

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'email-nonce' ) ) {
            die ('Email Busted!');


        }else{



        }
    }
```

Comment: Try appending current string with the nonce so that you wont get the same nonce again

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need not to create hidden fields use this it will create it automatically

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'your_action', 'put_name' ); ?>
```

while checking `if(wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'put_name' ], 'your_action' ))`
try this

Comment: I now have it working locally with wp_nonce_field and a few typos I had. My problem now is it won't work on the live server. On the live server I get 'Email Busted' which is when the wp_verify_nonce fails

Comment: you want to say that it goes in else condition verification fails?

Answer (score 1):

You could use *check_ajax_referrer*, there's an example in the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer

Answer (score 0):

You just do a little wrong here. The updated nonce field is below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ajax-nonce" id="ajax-nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'email-nonce' ); ?>" />
```